# .NET MAUI 8.0: Image Inside Frame Not Centering Correctly When Expanded

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm working on a .NET MAUI 8.0 project for Windows and facing an issue with centering an image inside a Frame. The image is not centered correctly, either when it is in its original state or when expanded through an animation.

Here's the XAML for the Frame and the Image:

```
<Frame BorderColor="Transparent" 
       CornerRadius="8" 
       WidthRequest="780" 
       HeightRequest="640"  
       HorizontalOptions="Start" 
       Margin="130"  
       x:Name="ImageFrame">
    <Image Margin="-20" 
           x:Name="MainImage" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           MaximumHeightRequest="1080"
           MaximumWidthRequest="1920"
           Aspect="AspectFill"
           Source="frog.jpg"/>
</Frame>
```

And here's the C# code for the expand animation:

```
private async void ExpandImgButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExpandImgButton.IsVisible = false;
    var timeSpan = 0.5;

    var widthAnimation = new Animation(v => ImageFrame.WidthRequest = v, 780, 1920);
    var heightAnimation = new Animation(v => ImageFrame.HeightRequest = v, 640, 1080);
    var marginAnimation = new Animation(v => ImageFrame.Margin = new Thickness(v, v, v, v), 130, 0);

    var parentAnimation = new Animation
    {
        { 0, 1, widthAnimation },
        { 0, 1, heightAnimation },
        { 0, 1, marginAnimation }
    };

    MainImage.MaximumHeightRequest = 1080;
    MainImage.MaximumWidthRequest = 1920;

    parentAnimation.Commit(this, "ExpandImage", 16, (uint)(timeSpan * 1000), Easing.CubicInOut, (v, c) => AnimationCompleted());
}
```

The issue is that the image does not appear centered within the frame, both in its original and expanded state. I've tried different Aspect settings, also tried to change the Frame into a Border but none seem to resolve the issue.

What I want is for the image to always be centered within its container, regardless of its size. How can I achieve this in .NET MAUI?

Comment: As far as I know, after uprading to Maui8, they broke images and imagebuttons (they don't scale correctly), also there're some problems with Frames. Try to use Border instead of Frame, I managed to fix most problems with this approach.

Comment: @SergTomcat, I forgot to put it in the question, but i already tried this solution with the same result. Edited the issue to reflect this. Thank you anyways

Comment: @verdu4l According to [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), can you add  `AnimationCompleted()` and the rest code to help reproduce the issue?